# Changing 2D Array in R. 1st Dimension is a Row Number, and 2nd Dimension is a Pixel with one dimension

Tags: r, arrays, tensorflow, matrix

I'm having some problem :

I have this matrix array :

[image: Matrix Array of Pixels]

The dimension is : [1] 27455   784

I want to transform the 2nd Dimension into 28 x 28 array

Basically I want to change it into Convolution2D Input Shape (n_samples, height, width, channels) for TensorFlow
The channels number is 1 because the image is in grayscale
How can I transform the 784 into 28x28 array and add another array as channels = 1 ?

Thanks a lot!

I try this :

```
 # reshape 1-D data into 3-D data
train_x_img <- train_x
dim(train_x_img) <- c(27455, 28,28)

test_x_img <- test_x
dim(test_x_img) <- c(7172, 28,28,)

# check the dimensions of the 3-D data

dim(train_x_img)
```

But I guess it is wrong, because the value is not inserted in a correct order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When R handles indexing for arrays or matrices, it assumes that the ordering as primarily on the columns. You, however, appear to want to create a 25 x 25 matrix-slice based on successive rows of that larger matrix, so the first thing to do is transpose so the row values are in columns columns:

```
train_x_img <- t( train_x )  # now  784 x 27455
```

Fold the previous row values, now in columns by re-dimensioning:

```
dim(train_x_img) <- c(28,28, 27455)
```

And now, because you want the third dimension to be recast as the first index,  use base R's `aperm` function:

```
train_x_img <- aperm(train_x_img, c(3, 1,2)
```

### Demonstration with a somewhat smaller object:

```
x  <- matrix(1:24, 4, 6)  # 4 x 6 example
 x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17   21   # desire rows to be "folded"
[2,]    2    6   10   14   18   22
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19   23
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20   24

a <- t(x)  # now 6 x 4
dim(a) <- c(2,3,4)  # fold the first dimension in two smaller dimensions
a2 <- aperm(a, c(3,1,2)) # reorder the indices

Examine the first entries indexed by the first index
 a2[1,,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    9   17
[2,]    5   13   21   # success, that matrix is composed of the first row of x
```

Comment: Hi, it works but how to add "grayscale" value in the matrix array?
I try to do this :

```{r eval}
dim(train_x_img) <- c(dim(train_x_img), 1)
dim(test_x_img) <- c(dim(test_x_img), 1)
dim(train_x_img)
dim(test_x_img)
```

but the result for fitting is error : 
IndexError: list index out of range

is it related?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "adding another channel" or "adding greyscale value". You now have 27455 square matrices that can be indexed. Are you asking how to add a 27456th square matrix that has greyscale values? If so you should put in the time to build a [MCVE] using an example of say 5  4 x 4 square matrices and ask for code that adds a sixth matrix of equal dimension. And .... DO NOT USE COMMENTS TO POST CODE. Learn to [edit] your question body for clarification.

Comment: sorry, I'm newbie :(
anyway, I'm using your solution for handling matrix and it's solve my problem! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that. If the problem had been how to append matrixes to an array the answer might have been abind in the abind package.

Comment: well, i just add dim() < c(24, 24, row number, 1). So basically the pixel value is already grayscale value, adding 1 to the last of vector just confirm it to the model CNN. I don't know why it works though hahaha

Comment: Do remember that R arrays and matrices will silently drop dimensions when the “width” of a slice is 1. To prevent that set drop=FALSE